# Typescript strictNullChecks with limited scope

Tags: typescript

I'm using the Ionic v2 beta with Typescript, and would love to use `--strictNullChecks`.  However, dependencies of my project, such as @angular/core, cause compilation errors when I put `strictNullChecks: true` in my `tsconfig.json`.

Is there a way to declare a directory / file / module / class as abiding by strictNullChecks, even when the overall project cannot be compiled with the flag?

It seems that, since `--strictNullChecks` is not the default, it will have extremely limited use (despite being an extremely useful feature) as a result of dependencies that were written without the flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dependencies are all in `.js` and `.d.ts` files (that is, not ts source) then you can use a flag and tell the compiler to skip checking your libs, which will result in no errors from the libs.

There are [two new flags](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for that:

`skipLibCheck`:

> Don’t check the default library (`lib.d.ts`) file’s validity

`skipDefaultLibCheck`:

> Don’t check a user-defined default library (`*.d.ts`) file’s validity

And a bit more about it in the [What's new in Typescript 2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#user-content-new---skiplibcheck):

> TypeScript 2.0 adds a new `--skipLibCheck` compiler option that causes
> type checking of declaration files (files with extension `.d.ts`) to be
> skipped. When a program includes large declaration files, the compiler
> spends a lot of time type checking declarations that are already known
> to not contain errors, and compile times may be significantly
> shortened by skipping declaration file type checks.
>
> Since declarations in one file can affect type checking in other
> files, some errors may not be detected when `--skipLibCheck` is
> specified. For example, if a non-declaration file augments a type
> declared in a declaration file, errors may result that are only
> reported when the declaration file is checked. However, in practice
> such situations are rare.

Comment: Thank you!  Putting `"skipLibCheck": false` in my `tsconfig` works in my case.  However, I'd still argue that either --strictNullChecks should be the default (forcing everyone to adapt their definitions appropriately) or there needs to be a way to integrate typescript code that doesn't adhere to strict null checks into a codebase that does.  I guess multiple `tsconfig` might be an option.

Comment: You can divide your project into two, each with its own tsconfig file. the one that uses strictNullChecks will then use the other project with its `.d.ts` files and so using skipLibCheck will make it work

Comment: Harder to setup, less compatible with e.g. Ionic v2, but yes, that is another workaround.

Comment: Is it also possible to skip checks for `node_modules` in general?

Comment: @Highmastdon using the `skipLibCheck` will skip checking `node_modules` as well

Comment: `skipLibCheck` does not skip general `*.ts` files even if they exist under `node_modules`.

Comment: @kimamula yeah, my bad.  simply add `node_modules` to the `exclude` part of the `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 26):

If you'd like to scope `strictNullChecks` to a particular directory within your project, you can do it with an `extends` clause in your `tsconfig.json`. For example, if your project looks like this:

```
a/
  code.ts
b/
  other.ts
tsconfig.json
```

And you want to enable strict null checking within `a`, you could add `a/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```

When you run `tsc` from inside directory `a`, you'll get strict null checks for `a/code.ts`.

This approach isn't without drawbacks:

- If `a/code.ts` imports `../b/other.ts`, then you'll get strict null checking for `b/other.ts`, too.
- If you run `tsc` from the root directory, you won't get strict null checking for `a/code.ts`.

You're effectively creating a new, strict, sub-project within your larger project. You'd want to make sure to run `tsc` for both projects as part of your build process. It's not perfect, but it might help you migrate a large project to `strictNullChecks` bit by bit.

Comment: @Marecky What does it matter what IDE you use? It should work if you use the CLI directly.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to declare a directory / file / module / class as abiding by strictNullChecks, even when the overall project cannot be compiled with the flag

No.

Note: There is a feature request to ignore errors for certain files that hasn't come to fruitation : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11051

Answer (score 2):

No.

`strictNullChecks` works by removing the `undefined` and `null` values from the domains of all types. It's a global setting that changes how all interpretations of types behave.

There's not even a coherent definition of what it would mean to have one file or module or class where this flag is off -- it'd be like having the laws of physics be different in one country versus another, even though you can freely ship goods and people between those countries.

Comment: The physics _are_ completely different, that's the problem.  That's why something like this is needed - you can't control other people's code, but you do have to work with it.

Comment: It would mean that `string`, for example, actually means `string | null` in one file, and just `string` without a null in another file. This option would be pretty useless unless typechecker has the ability to generate intelligent error messages explaining why one value has the type incompatible with another, in every possible case.

Comment: It's super unclear regardless. What if a non-nullable file said `type MyStr = string;` and a nullable file said `type MyStr2 = MyStr;` ? Is `MyStr2` nullable or not? It'd be impossible to reason about.

Comment: `type`, by definition, is just an alias, it should not affect anything, so in this case nullability is determined by the file where original `string` is coming from.  But I agree - while it's possible to invent rules for everything, this is really extremely confusing, impossible to explain, hard to define and implement correctly and will lead to countless questions from puzzled users.

Comment: @artem is correct, it would be easy to infer whether a specific `string` is nullable based on the source module of that specific `string` type and whether it came from a file with strictNullChecks or not (the `let` would copy the source type's semantics).  I understand that this might add confusion, but it's already an opt-in choice to have null checking, and it already produces a lot of confusing errors outside of the user's code.  It makes sense to add some flexibility so that users can interact with code outside of their own.

Comment: There is one use case which is well-served by a per-file nullable flag _independent of the reconciliation rules_: the incremental transition of a codebase from strict-nullable-unsafe to -safe with e.g. an automated PR rejection hook in case of compiler errors. Gradually add one more file to the null-safe set and deal with the errors; that lets you eventually add all files to that set without having a flag day. This of course doesn't address the library/dependency issue. [This comment is re: @artem and Ryan Cavanaugh]

Comment: Strict null checks for local variables, at the minimum, is possible and would be valuable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [typescript-strict-plugin](https://github.com/allegro/typescript-strict-plugin) which allows you to turn on strict mode in specific files or directories. It does not work with specific tsc options though.