# tsconfig.json doesn't exclude folder node_modules properly

Tags: angular, build, alfresco, node-modules, tsconfig

Im trying to build my project by command **npm run ng build**, but it prints me errors from folder **node_modules** like this. (Because of rules in tsconfig.json.)

```
node_modules/@alfresco/js-api/src/api/gs-core-rest-api/model/filePlan.ts:46:13 - error TS2322: Type 'UserInfo | undefined' is not assignable to type 'UserInfo'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'UserInfo'.

node_modules/@alfresco/js-api/src/authentication/oauth2Auth.ts:243:36 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

node_modules/@alfresco/js-api/src/authentication/processAuth.ts:180:9 - error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
```

But folder **node_modules** is in **exclude** parameter of tsconfig.json. Rules should ignore folder **node_modules**.

Here is tsconfig.json.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {}
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*", "test.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

I want to ignore errors in folder **node_modules**. Rules should apply on folder **src**.

Thank you for reading. I appreciate every answer. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely not a problem with `node_modules`. It is because of

```
"strictNullChecks": true
```

Somewhere in your code you are assigning a nullable variable to a non-nullable variable, or something of the sort.

Comment: No no, strict null checking is ok, but problem is, that scripts from node_modules are checked by the typescript in build. Tsconfig rules must be only for developer's code, so only directory "src". If i will run build, than i would like to see only errors and warnings from my code, not from node_modules.

Comment: I am assigning a nullable variable to a non-nullable variable inside folder node_modules. My intention is to ignore errors in folder node_modules.

Comment: @PavelFiala What version of typescript are you using?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis I am using typescript version 3.5.3.

Comment: This might be a problem you can't avoid. If the library you are importing itself isn't compliant with `strictNullChecks`, then there isn't much you can do.

Please read this thread as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164034/typescript-strictnullchecks-with-limited-scope

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Null- and undefined-aware types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html), it tells TS there could be chances of getting null or undefined, which are valid cases

```
// Compiled with --strictNullChecks
let x: number;
let y: number | undefined;
let z: number | null | undefined;
```